# How to create page of multiple entity reference fields

Tags: nodes

I'm making a kickboxing archive. I would like to create a content type 'Fights'. But something isn't working.

A fight takes place between 2 fighters (content type 'Fighters'), at an event (content type 'Events'), in a venue (content type='Venues').

I need to select two fighters. I have added an entity reference of 'field_fighters'. Now I want to add another entity reference of the same field for fighter 2, but I can only refer to this field once. How can I do this?

Comment: Allow 2 values in field 1?

Answer (score 3):

In the parameter of your entity reference field, you can set the number of values allowed. Just set it to 2 to answer your needs.